# select statement with count for months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, count, average

Hi I am trying to create select which will count pickups from pickup table by months. 
Select will be used in web site written on .NET.

Report will looks like this 
[image: example pf report which i am trying to create]

I have 3 tables

```
 create table Agency
    (
    AgencyID int not null IDENTITY, 
    AgencyName varchar (100)not null,
    CeresNo VARCHAR(7), 
   AgencyCode varchar (16) not null,
    Active bit,    
    CensusDist varchar(50) ,    
    GroupCode varchar (10),    
    Primary Key (AgencyID),    
    FOREIGN KEY (CensusDist) REFERENCES AgencyCensus(CensusDist),    
    FOREIGN KEY (GroupCode) REFERENCES AgencyGroup (GroupCode)
    );
```

Clients table

```
 create table Clients
    (
    ClientID int not null IDENTITY (9000,1), 
    AgencyID int not null,
    AppDate date not null,
    CertifiedDate date ,
    Primary Key (ClientID),   
   FOREIGN KEY (AgencyID) REFERENCES Agency(AgencyID), 
    );
```

and pickup table

```
create table Pickup

(
PickupID int IDENTITY,
ClientID int ,
PickupDate date ,
PickupProxy  varchar (200) ,
PickupHispanic bit default 0,
EthnCode varchar(5) ,
CategCode varchar (2) ,
AgencyID int,
Primary Key (PickupID),
FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES Clients (ClientID)
);
```

so far i have this statement

```
select 
[Agency]= (select AgencyName from agency),
 [Jan] = (select count(pickupid)   from  pickup where PickupDate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31' group by AgencyID),
 [FEB] = (select count(pickupid)  from  pickup where PickupDate between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-29' group by AgencyID  )
```

The select is not finished and probably should be rewrited but i dont know how :( 
it throwing errors

**Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Also problem is i don't know how to make statement look at records in pickup table with current year. Because I think people who will use web site will not be able change dates in select :) Also for some reason function AVG doesn't calculate correct average and doesn't want to do it by groups. Please help!

Comment: If you create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some example data you will probably get answers faster.

Comment: I cannot understand how does it works :)

Comment: SQLFiddle don understand :) there is no even help page:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Alter procedure sp_CountPickups
 @MyYear int
AS
SELECT
MAX(a.AgencyName),
COUNT(PickupID) as YearTotal,
COUNT(PickupID)/(CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) =@myYear THEN MONTH(GETDATE()) ELSE 12 END) as MoAvg,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Jan,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Feb,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Mar,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Apr, 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as May,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Jun,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Jul,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Aug, 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Sep,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Oct,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Nov,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Dec 
FROM dbo.Pickup p join Agency a on p.agencyid = a.agencyid
where DATEPART(year, PickupDate) = @MyYear
group by a.AgencyID 
order by a.AgencyID
```

may be will be useful for somebody

Answer (score 2):

You have not given sufficient details about how you expect the Average to be calaculated, but the rest can be calculated as follows:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(PickupID) as YearTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Feb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 3  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Mar,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 4  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Apr,            
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 5  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 6  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Jun,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Jul,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 8  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Aug, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 9  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Sep,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 10  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Oct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 11  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Nov,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, PickupDate) = 12  THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Dec         
FROM dbo.Pickup 
where DATEPART(year, PickupDate) = 2012
group by AgencyID
```

Where the year in question (2012 here) is supplied as a parameter. You will either need to perform the lookup of `AgencyId`  into `AgencyName` on the report **OR** use the above query in a dervived table and join it to the `Agency` table.

Comment: Thanx! As I understand requirements MoAVG it Yeartotal divided to 12 and round to closest full number. Also did not get how to show AgencyNAme because this two tables do not have direct relationship they connect to each other trough  Clients  table. So that means I need add 3 table Join?

Comment: "Also did not get how to show AgencyNAme because this two tables do not have direct relationship they connect to each other trough Clients table" - that's not what your schema definition implies.

Comment: Pickup table has this field `AgencyID` but it is not FOREIGN key, or I still can connect them by same field? Because in college they  teach us  we have to join table s only by FOREIGN or primary keys.

Comment: Then you have a missing FK constraint

Comment: no the problem  with this  table it when client  make pickup his/hers current agencyid and other stuff inserted in this table fron Client  table, because in Example this  month  client  did pickup in agency 1 but  next  month he did it in agency 2 if Agency  will be FK  it  will change on  current agency and it will be impossible to trace where they did pickups in past. because of that it is not FK

Comment: It's still an FK as far as Pickup is concerned. Anyway: I'm past my point of diminishing return.